# OKE application don't connect internal ClusterIP Service

Tags: kubernetes

I have a application with 3 components, API-server, Postgresql vector database and RASA NLP/NLU.
I created a deployment to API-server with 2 replicas and created a service type LoadBalancer to receive http request from a external application. This working.
Also created a deployment to RASA with 1 replica e a service to allow internal applications access the port 5005 with type=ClusterIP.
When API-server receive a request a request POST is created and send to RASA service but receive an erro: "Failed to parse: http://rasa:tcp://10.96.112.209:5005/model/parse”. I expected url http://rasa:5005/model/parse but including a IP Address unknow.
[erro log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2vWO.png)

Deployment manifests:

````
    NAME           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
    ally-backend   2/2     2            2           27h
    pgvector       2/2     2            2           26h
    rasa           1/1     1            1           46h

    [opc@bastiao-oke ~]$ k describe svc rasa
    Name:              rasa
    Namespace:         hml
    Labels:            app=rasa
    Annotations:       <none>
    Selector:          app=rasa
    Type:              ClusterIP
    IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
    IP Families:       IPv4
    IP:                10.96.197.243
    IPs:               10.96.197.243
    Port:              <unset>  5005/TCP
    TargetPort:        5005/TCP
    Endpoints:         10.244.0.176:5005
    Session Affinity:  None
    Events:            <none>

    [opc@bastiao.oke ~]$k logs service/ally-backend
    INFO:root:Verificando 'Intents' no RASA-NLU
    INFO:root:Identificado algum problema no acesso ao servidor  RASA  - Failed to parse: 
    http://rasa:tcp://10.96.112.209:5005/model/parse
    INFO:openai:message='OpenAI API response' 
    path=https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions 
    processing_ms=549 request_id=4216ee870acf941306cbfb78874f4803 
    response_code=200
    Error submitting packet: [Errno 111] Connection refused, 
    dropping the packet and closing the socket, 3 additional 
    messages skipped
    WARNING:ddtrace.vendor.dogstatsd:Error submitting packet: 
    [Errno 111] Connection refused, dropping the packet and closing 
    the socket, 3 additional messages skipped
    INFO:root:Sentimento identificado na query: 'Neutro ou 
    Positivo'
    INFO:root:Verificando 'Intents' no RASA-NLU
    INFO:root:Identificado algum problema no acesso ao servidor  
    RASA  - Failed to parse: 
    http://rasa:tcp://10.96.112.209:5005/model/parse```


Accessing rasa service from a pod ally-backend:

    ```root@ally-backend-65bf557648-tqmw2:/core# curl --request POST 
    rasa:5005/model/parse -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d 
    '{"text": "Boa noite"}' -v
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already 
    inferred.
    *   Trying 10.96.197.243:5005...
    * Connected to rasa (10.96.197.243) port 5005 (#0)
    > POST /model/parse HTTP/1.1
    > Host: rasa:5005
    > User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
    > Accept: */*
    > Content-Type: application/json
    > Content-Length: 21
    > 
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Access-Control-Expose-Headers: filename
    < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    < content-length: 544
    < connection: keep-alive
    < content-type: application/json
    < 
    * Connection #0 to host rasa left intact
    {"text":"Boa noite","intent": 
    {"name":"saudacao","confidence":0.9999688863754272},"entities": 
    [],"text_tokens":[[0,3],[4,9]],"intent_ranking": 
    [{"name":"saudacao","confidence":0.9999688863754272}, 
    {"name":"finalizar","confidence":2.5454630304011516e-5}, 
    {"name":"agradecimento","confidence":2.8781237233488355e-6}, 
    {"name":"out_of_scope","confidence":2.794123474814114e- 
    6}],"response_selector":{"all_retrieval_intents":[],"default": 
    {"response": {"responses":null,"confidence":0.0,"intent_response_key":null,"utter_action":root@ally-root@ally-root@ally-root@ally-root@ally-backeroot@ally-backeroot@root@ally-root@ally-root@ally-backend-65bf557648-tqmw2:/core# 
root@ally-backend-65bf557648-tqmw2:/core# curl --request POST rasa:5005/model/parse -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": "Boa noite"}' -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 10.96.197.243:5005...
* Connected to rasa (10.96.197.243) port 5005 (#0)
> POST /model/parse HTTP/1.1
> Host: rasa:5005
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 21
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: filename
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< content-length: 544
< connection: keep-alive
< content-type: application/json
< 
* Connection #0 to host rasa left intact
{"text":"Boa noite","intent":{"name":"saudacao","confidence":0.9999688863754272},"entities":[],"text_tokens":[[0,3],[4,9]],"intent_ranking":[{"name":"saudacao","confidence":0.9999688863754272},{"name":"finalizar","confidence":2.5454630304011516e-5},{"name":"agradecimento","confidence":2.8781237233488355e-6},{"name":"out_of_scope","confidence":2.794123474814114e-6}],"response_selector":{"all_retrieval_intents":[],"default":{"response":{"responses":null,"confidence":0.0,"intent_responsroot@ally-backend-65bf557648-tqmw2:/core# ```


Thank you in advance for your help.
````

Comment: Don't post images, copy the text instead.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved!
When executed a command:

`kubectl exec ally-backend-7944d55b4-b72hd -- printenv \ grep SERVICE`

An environment variable pointed the RASA service to a non-existent IP, probably an IP used at some other time by the service.

So, I included spec.enableService.link as false and recreated the deployment.

Everything working.